# Why does GDM run on TTY1 and gnome-shell on TTY2?

Tags: tty, gdm

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 with gnome-shell 3.20.4.
I usually see my graphic interface run on TTY7. But now (new install) I see GDM run on TTY1 and my graphic interface on TTY2. Why GDM and gnome-shell are separate? And why it's run graphic interface on TTY2 and not in TTY7. It is a wrong configuration or it is totally normal to see this ?

On my TTY7 I can see : `/dev/sda4/ clean: xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks`

Comment: I have the same problem running unstable Debian after recent upgrade. I am running gnome-shell 3.22.2-1 and gdm 3.22.1-1.

Comment: If you see the date of the post, my question is older than yours...

Answer (score 4):

I found an [explanation](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747339) on Gnome's Bugzilla, see below. Hopefully they will address the increased memory consumption by tearing down the greeter after user login.

> GDM's behavior was changed in 3.16 so that instead of running one X server on the login screen which is then transformed into the user's session, we now start a new X session from within the user's session, which means that we need to start the user's session on another TTY/VT.
>
> Note that when using fast user switching, you effectively got this behavior as well, with each user on a different TTY/VT. We just extended it to the first user to log in as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info. I'm new to hacking virtual terminals and this is interesting.