# How to restart gdm on login loop from tty?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, login, lightdm, gdm

When using `lightdm`, when encountering a login loop after waking from sleep I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to drop into `tty5` for example. After logging in, I write `sudo service lightdm restart` into the terminal, which logs out of the current session and brings me to a fresh login screen, thereby escaping the login loop.

However, when using `gdm3`, I cannot exit a login loop from `tty5` using `sudo serivce gdm restart` in this way.  The screen just turns black and the whole system needs a hard restart using the power button.  I understand that `gdm` [operates differently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910108/why-is-my-gdm-at-a-different-tty-than-my-desktop-environment) from `lightdm`.  My question is:

> What commands do I need to write in a tty to escape a login loop when using gdm?

Comment: I am having the same issue but in 20.04