# cannot easily switch to virtual consoles -- why?

Tags: command-line, virtual-console, tui

I can only login to a virtual console by using `ctrl-alt-f4` as `f1` brings me to a login screen (like `windows_key-l` to lock) and `f3` has no result.

This defies my expectations.

While I haven't swapped out keyboards yet, this only happened after installing 20.04.  Is something different about virtual consoles?

references:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/console.4.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is something different about the virtual consoles depending on which version of Ubuntu you have updated from.

On older versions of Ubuntu, lightdm was present on TTY7. However on newer versions, GDM is present on TTY1 and TTY2.

So on 20.04, you should be able to access a virtual console on TTY3~TTY8.

Please see [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/965201/167115) if you would like a more in depth answer as to why you see both a lockscreen on TTY1 and a normal session on TTY2. However, I don't think installing lightdm is necessary as the answer suggests.